# Forces of constraint and Lagrangian in a half Atwood Machine with a real pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

I was thinking about this problem and had some trouble about the constraint equation.It's just a pulley with mass and moment of inercia $I$ that is atached to two blocks, just like in the picture. And I was tring to solve it using Lagragian Mechanics.Do I have to write:

$x+y=l$ and

$x=R\theta$

And them my constrant equation would be:

$f=R\theta+y-l=0$

Or just one of them is enough?

I can't see if this equations are enough to describe the whole system or if I need just one of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Atwood machine has one generalized coordinate , hence you need two constraint equations  which are

$$x=R\theta\\ 
y=R\theta$$

with the kinetic energy

$$T=\frac 12\left(m_1\,\dot x^2+m_2\,\dot y^2+I_r\,\dot\theta^2\right)$$

, the potential energy

$$U=m_2\,g\,y$$

and EL you obtain the equation of motion
$~\ddot\theta=\ldots$